# Bug re-enables a TextBox if it has Cond. Formatting?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I think I'm looking directly at an Access 2003 bug.   Here's what I did (I think):

1. I'm developing a Continuous Form (i.e. multiple records per page).
2. I have an unbound textbox in the background of the Details section.  Under *Data Properties*, I have *Enabled*=No and *Locked*=Yes. (In other words, I don't want the user to select it. I only want it for the background color)
3. This textbox also has some conditional formatting to change the background color for that row. (e.g. If we haven't spoken to that customer in awhile, the background for that record is red)
4. If I choose a record where the conditional formatting is active (i.e. the background is red), I can actually click on this textbox.  There's not much that I can do, of course, but this shouldn't happen and surely would be confusing to the end-users.

Has anyone else seen this? What's your workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enabled` is a property that can be controlled via conditional formatting.  By default when you add a new condition, the `Enabled` property is set to True.  **If you don't want your control to be enabled you must explicitly set Enabled = False within the conditional formatting rule.**

The property is toggled via a button in the lower right corner of the conditional formatting dialog.  It's easy to miss (I forget about it all the time).

Personally, I think the property should be three-way: True, False, or Inherit (with Inherit as the default).  Unfortunately, Access forces you to be explicit when adding conditional formatting rules and state whether the rule should make the control Enabled or Disabled.

Comment: Thanks to you, I learned something today! It's obvious now, but I always thought that button was for Sunken Borders and ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my workaround (I was waiting to see if anyone else would suggest something better.  Apparently not.)

1. In my conditionally formatted textbox, add an Event Procedure for GotFocus.  Enter this code: `Me.Txt_FocusHere.SetFocus`.
2. Make a 2nd unbound text box somewhere on the form.  Shrink it until it's just 1 line thick.  Call it `Txt_FocusHere`.

So whenever the user clicks on the colored background, the focus is immediately taken to this dummy textbox which can't store any data and is so small that the user doesn't see the blinking cursor.

Comment: Have you done "send to back"? And have you considered setting focus to `Screen.PreviousControl` instead of creating a control for no purpose other than receiving the focus? If you worry that somehow the previous control to have the focus won't be accessible, you could instead do something like setting `Me.Section(0).Controls("SomeOtherControl").SetFocus`.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know there was a PreviousControl.  But luckily the issue moot thanks to mwolfe02.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used the method on the following page:  http://www.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0047.htm - "Changing the Background Color of the Current Record in a Continuous Form"

Comment: Thanks, I've seen that before. It probably works, but it also looks unnecessarily complex for this detail task.